# Error installing capybara 0.8.0 on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, capybara-webkit

I'm quite new using Ruby and I need to install a rails server on Windows 7 in order to test few application in IE.

I did everything good (I hope) but now when I try to run `bundle install` on cmd I receive this error:

```
An error occured while installing capybara-webkit (0.8.0), and Bundler cannot co
ntinue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.8.0'` succeeds before bundling
.
```

How can I install capybara-webkit on Windows 7?

I also tried to follow other instructions found here on Stackoverflow to run the Bundle without test, but it doesn't work.

I hope you can help.

I can not build a VM on Ubuntu, so don't suggest me to do that and I don't have a Mac.

---

Error installing capybara-webkit -v '0.8.0':

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

which: no qmake in (.;C:\Ruby\DevKit\bin;C:\Ruby\DevKit\mingw\bin;C:\Program Fil
es\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common File
s\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System
32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Blu
etooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program
 Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broa
dcom 802.11 Network Adapter;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Progra
m Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Bi
nn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Micro
soft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\To
ols\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DT
S\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Micros
oft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin:C:\Wind
ows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Ruby\bin;C:
\Ruby193\bin)
which: no qmake-qt4 in (.;C:\Ruby\DevKit\bin;C:\Ruby\DevKit\mingw\bin;C:\Program
 Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Sy
stem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM
\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\
Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Pr
ogram Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tool
s\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\M
icrosoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\10
0\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\10
0\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Mi
crosoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin:C:\
Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Ruby\bi
n;C:\Ruby193\bin)

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-web
kit-0.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.8.0/./gem_m
ake.out

Comment: what's the error when you try `gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.8.0'`

Comment: so, the error is: it couldn't find qmake on your box.

Comment: You haven't got QT installed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480048/capybara-webkit-0-8-0-failed-to-build-on-window-7