# Can't install capybara-webkit in Windows Server 2008 R2 / Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, installation, capybara-webkit

I need to run tests in Jenkins which is installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, so the advices to run bundle install without "test" section do not fit here.

I NEED to have capybara-webkit be installed in Windows. The error message I'm getting, includes, as always, native extensions:

```
Installing capybara-webkit (0.12.0) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.0/./gem_make.out
```

Native QT components seem to be installed (I have downloaded 1,7 GB (!!!) distribution package and installed it). Enhancing PATH does not help.

DevKit is installed too.

Comment: If gem_make.out is the log file you are talking about, then it contains nothing more than "C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb" line.

Comment: I am having this exact problem (http://stackoverflow.com/q/12936623/1157054), please let me know if you are able to get it working for you.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message?

You need all the right versions of QT, mingw, your path updated, and then to run everything here https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit in the right way... Make sure you're in the pkg directory at the end.

See [capybara-webkit (0.8.0) failed to build on window 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480048/capybara-webkit-0-8-0-failed-to-build-on-window-7)